# Scala Compiler not found in Intellij IDEA 11 with Play 2.0 project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.0

I created a project using the typical `play new`, and then I used `play idea` to generate the .iml file. When I imported the .iml file into Intellij IDEA, I could not figure out how to get the compiler library to recognize. Below are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is a slight weirdness with the Scala settings in IntelliJ. Currently the only way to register a scala distribution is to create a new project.

Steps:

1. File > New Project > Create project from scratch
2. Leave all settings as default. Project name can be anything.
3. On the "Please select the desired technologies" page, choose Scala. Some GUI elements will appear that allow you to tell IntelliJ how to find your scala compiler and library. Make sure to set the "Level" options to "global".
4. Click Finish. Close the dummy project that you created, and go back to your real project. The Scala compiler that you registered should now be in the list on your project settings page.

Comment: You're right. Once I created a brand new project with defaults (including default module), and set the Scala compiler to global, I was able to use it in the project I wanted to :)

Comment: In 11.1.2 I don't see the "Please select the desired technologies" page and Scala is not appearing in the Modules list (but I have the plugin).

Comment: @mkraken did you try re-installing the Scala plugin as suggested in rintcius's answer?

Comment: @ChrisB I did.  That didn't fix it.  I think what worked was to add the compiler manually as a library (I added the scala-compiler.jar from the scala install directory). But, for some reason I had to add each of the jars one by one.  I have an older version of the compiler which maybe the plugin wasn't defaulting to.

Comment: While Scala is great as a language, the fragility of the development tools (except for command line) is breathtaking. I hope in 5 years they'll be where current C++ debuggers are. Thanks for this answer - gave me some understanding. What I would like is for IntelliJ to detect my existing 'brew' scala installation, not needing to download another set just to please the IDE.

Answer (score 19):

A variation that worked for me: drop the Scala facet and run 'Add framework support...' again.

1. File / Project Structure / Facets
2. Click Scala facet then minus to remove Scala facet from your module.  Click OK.
3. Right click your project/module, 'Add Framework Support...', choose Scala.
4. Enter the path to your Scala compiler and library.

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this problem, but the workaround as described by Chris B did not work for me, since in my case "Scala" was missing on the "Please select the desired technologies" page.

In my case the problem appeared to be an incompatible Scala plugin. After I reinstalled the Scala plugin it worked fine.

Comment: Upgrading the plugin fixed it for me.