# Scala not being evaluated on Intellij Scala plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Coming from an Eclipse background im trying to learn how to use IntelliJ with Scala. 
I've downloaded the plugin and restarted. However when I create a new project, then worksheet the expressions are not being evaluated :

[image]

I don't know what the issue is or how to find if Intellij is reporting an issue ? In Eclipse I would check the problems tab. Is there something similar I can check or an alternative method to get this to work ?

Comment: That's strange. The same code compiles and outputs correctly in my IDE. It take time for it to run, however, output on the right pane appears with a delay. Maybe this is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching I came across this question : [Scala Compiler not found in Intellij IDEA 11 with Play 2.0 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407777/scala-compiler-not-found-in-intellij-idea-11-with-play-2-0-project)

Using answer by "Chris B" allowed me to create a new project with the Scala library. Hopefully this will be fixed in next release of plugin.

The problem for me was that "Compile library" is always "None", even when I select a library and click "Ok". Interestingly When I select the library the "Apply" button is disabled, maybe its a clue as to whats going on.

Anyway, when I follow the steps in linked question this is now my project facet :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually start my IntelliJ worksheet with

```
object Scribble extends App {
... // Your code goes here
}
```

This works then with both, worksheet mode and plain Scala mode.

Answer (score 0):

We are planning to publish musch better and faster worksheet version next week. Most probably your issue will be fixed.

Best regards,
Alexander Podkhlayuzin.